# iOS VPN Application using Tunnel Mode with Network extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, vpn, networkextension

Currently Personal iOS Vpn Application implemented using IKEv2 protocol and network extension api but i want implement same thing using Network extension with packet Tunnel provider in tunnel mode.

So can explain clear architecture how to implement and what are library need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look through (and built) the [SimpleTunnel](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleTunnel/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code. It shows how basic Packet Tunnel and App Proxy providers are set up.